# Play Framework with eclipselink error on change and reload

Tags: java, jpa, playframework-2.0, eclipselink

Im faced with some problems for the integration of eclipselink into the play framework. When I type run the server starts and I can connect to my application without any error.

But: Afterwards when I (as an example) force a recompile with a little change then the application breaks with an error (on em.persist):

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[IllegalArgumentException: Object: model.Car@1a5f139c is not a known entity type.]]
```

What I did(to keep it simple) a car model:

```
package model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int carId;

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

My build.sbt looks like this:

```
name := "WebTest"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
 "org.eclipse.persistence" % "eclipselink" % "2.5.1",
 "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache
)     


play.Project.playJavaSettings
```

application.conf(partially):

```
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS

db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/playjpa?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
db.default.user=xxxx
db.default.password=xxxx

jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit
```

Ans my persistence.xml in conf.META-INFO(drop create was in there before):

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>model.Car</class>

        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
         <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And now the controller which executes the call:

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "defaultPersistenceUnit";
    private static EntityManagerFactory factory;

    public static Result index() {
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        Car car = new Car();
        car.setName("Supercar");

        em.persist(car);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();

        return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem myself:

The key is to annotate with @Transactional. But before the build.sbt has to be modified like this

```
 "org.eclipse.persistence" % "eclipselink" % "2.5.1",
 "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
  javaJdbc,
  javaJpa
```

And in the play console you have to "reload". And only if "eclipse" and import the project again(at least my eclipse didnt like it) you can import the

```
import play.db.jpa.Transactional;
```

And over

```
JPA.em()
```

you can get the entitymanager.